# What exactly is the orange insulation foam used on many different launch vehicle stages?

Tags: rockets, space-shuttle, materials, insulation

What exactly is that orange/rust coloured insulation foam on the Space Shuttle external tank, the H-IIA/B, Delta-IV, and so many other launch vehicles? I remember finding the name of it in a NASA document somewhere but it has since escaped my memory (it was a combination of two different compounds if I remember correctly).

Note that I am asking what type of material this is, I understand very well the purpose of thermal insulation foam.

Comment: This is not very helpful, but in the industry it’s known as SOFI, for spray-on foam insulation. I know that sounds useless, but if you say SOFI (sounds like: Sofie) in the right circles, everyone knows what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, the Shuttle ET document in the answer also mentions SLA ("slaw").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At least for the Shuttle ET:

> The tank’s foam is a polyurethane-type foam composed of five  primary
>   ingredients: polymeric isocyanate, a flame retardant, a  surfactant, a
>   blowing agent, and a catalyst. A surfactant controls  the surface
>   tension of a liquid and thus cell formation. The blowing agent, HCFC
>   141b, creates the foam’s cellular structure by  making millions of
>   tiny bubbles or foam cells.

And

> There are four specially engineered closed-cell foams used on  the
>   tank. The larger sections of the tank are covered in NCFI  24-124,
>   which accounts for 77 per cent of the total foam used on  the tank.
>   NCFI 24-57, which has a slightly different formulation than  NCFI
>   24-124, is used on the aft dome, or bottom, of the liquid  hydrogen
>   tank. PDL 1034, hand-poured foam used for filling  odd-shaped
>   cavities, and BX 250/265 foam is used on the tank’s  “closeout”
>   areas. During the early days of the External Tank’s  development,
>   PDL was an acronym for Product Development  Laboratory, the first
>   supplier of that foam.  NCFI 24-124 and NCFI 24-57 are mechanically
>   sprayed foams;  BX 250/265 are applied mechanically on the feedlines
>   and domes  inside of the intertank and manually-applied, or
>   hand-sprayed in  the closeout areas.

Note: NCFI stands for [North Carolina Foam Industries](http://www.ncfi.com/).

From [here](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/114022main_TPS_FS.pdf).

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly the document I was searching for! Thank you!

Comment: Would you say that ["...in the industry it’s known as SOFI, for spray-on foam insulation."](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12671/what-exactly-is-the-orange-insulation-foam-used-on-many-different-launch-vehicle#comment33093_12671) I've suggested so in [Why would rocket bodies use specifically ablative coatings to reduce boil-off of cryogenic propellants? Is ablation important for this?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35271/12102)

Comment: The acronym SOFI was certainly used for some kind of ET foam. I suspect to an ET foam guy it had a very specific meaning but I am not that guy.